# Create tree bookmarks from XML in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, xml, pdf, itext

I want create tree bookmarks in pdf. I know, that I can creat this with `PdfOutline` class. I created bookmarks without ramification. How can I create tree bookmarks using XML file?

This is my XML file:

```
<node text="****" path="" type="book">
 <node text="******" path="" type="part">
   <node text="********" path="" type="chapter">
    <node text="**********" path="" type="subject">
      <node text="*********" path="####.htm" type="frame" />
      <node text="****" path="###.htm" type="frame" />
      <node text="*******" path="######.htm" type="frame" />
      <node text="********" path="#####.htm" type="frame" />
    </node>
   </node>
  </node>
 </node>
```

I create content of PDf file using XML file and  HTML file.
In XML file are headlines("text"). I'm parsing xml file and drag nodes.

How can I create tree bookmarks?

Now I'm getting bookmarks just without ramification. Maybe should I use recursion? But I don't understand how. Because, I should add to `PdfOutline()` child, but where am I can take child?

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, KeyValuePair<string, int>> entry in entries)
        {
            KeyValuePair<string, int> value = entry.Value;

            bookmark = new PdfOutline(root, PdfAction.GotoLocalPage(value.Value, new PdfDestination(value.Value), writer), entry.Key, true);

        }
```

Thank you.

Comment: try to use XPath to parse the XML.

Comment: But I need not only XML data. I need also destinations to pages with chapters in PDf.

Comment: Your XML is all wrong. Please take a look at the answer to the duplicate question to find out what the XML should look like. You also need to use the `SimpleBookmark` class to import the XML.

Comment: You didn't understand. I don't use existing pdf file. I create it by using xml and html. In xml there are titles and in html there are contents. How can I create bookmarks with ramification? What should I use? `SimpleBookmark`? Should I use `exportToXml()` and next  `importFromXML()`? Are you sure? And why?